use ENV variable in EntryPoint for Distroless image
I have 2 different applications (web apps) and 1 common Dockerfile through which i am building the apps and containerize it.
So far i was using full fledged images (debian); where in i was passing the exe name into the entrypoint as environment variable.
Now i was playing with distroless and its great. It offers lot size reduction. So i was doing the same and hit a road block.
I am unable to pass the environment variable to the entry point vector as shown:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ARG csprojFileName
COPY . /home/src
RUN dotnet publish "$csprojFileName.csproj"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:8.0-noble-chiseled
ARG csprojFileName
ENV CSPROJFILENAME $csprojFileName
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["./$CSPROJFILENAME"]

i tried changing ENTRYPOINT as ENTRYPOINT ["./${CSPROJFILENAME}"]; but no luck.
Please help; what could be the alternative approach if above is not supported?

Can  you build a separate Dockerfile for each component, with a fixed project name?  Also see Use environment variables in CMD: you need to use the shell-form of ENTRYPOINT or CMD for environment-variable expansion to be possible.

Yes separate dockerfile would be the easiest approach. I wanted to avoid that.
Also the distroless images do not have shell. Hence can not use that way.

In ENTRYPOINT and CMD (and RUN) Docker depends on the container's shell to do environment variable expansion and other shell-like task; if the image doesn't have a shell then you can't use environment variables or other shell syntax in those directives.
